# Application Cache : why Chrome show some files underlined in the console log?

Tags: google-chrome, application-cache

During an application cache update, Chrome logs :

> Application Cache Progress event (1 of 2) https://example.com/file1.css
>
> Application Cache Progress event (2 of 2) https://example.com/file2.js

[image]

Sometimes the URL is underlined (event 3/4 in this example), sometimes not. Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that underlined resources will be opened in developer tools when clicked on. Those that are not underlined, are still hyper-links but Chrome will launch them in a separate tab.

What I don't understand is why Chrome sometimes decides to treat resources like this and sometimes not. Even loading the same page several times changes the resources that are underlined occasionally.

Very odd. At a guess I'd say a bug.

Comment: I've look for the source, and found the message generated here : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/content/child/appcache/web_application_cache_host_impl.cc&q=%22Application%20Cache%20Progress%20event%22&sq=package:chromium&l=130  with the call to url.spec().c_str() So I'm guessing none of them decided to underline the text. My best guess is the console decide itself to underline it. I'll say : if the console detect it's a currently loaded file, it will underline it.